# How to increase a pandas row index in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, indexing, foursquare

I'm triying to increase the index of a row to get Foursquare's URls and then store it in other row in the same Dataset.
I know this is not a difficult task but I'm a newbie and cannot see my mistake.

I will only show the loop:

```
i=0
venue_id=df['id'][i] #I try to run the variable before and after the loop
for d in df['id']:
        #venue_id=df['id'][i]
        url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{}?client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}'.format(venue_id, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VERSION)
        i=+1
        print(url)
        #venue_id=df['id'][+1] also try this but the result was always the same
```

Result

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/557cda70498ec1b1d7c9bb38?client_id=WBVLIFMOB2B3KREKEPVECFKFZDJQJS2MCIXLERFTE4RZW0XA&client_secret=34TXWPRANTJP2E5QDBIKWEFTTPUKU3TOR2TR1I3GI0W4QY1X&v=20190101
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4d51750c7ee1a35d36e68f34?client_id=WBVLIFMOB2B3KREKEPVECFKFZDJQJS2MCIXLERFTE4RZW0XA&client_secret=34TXWPRANTJP2E5QDBIKWEFTTPUKU3TOR2TR1I3GI0W4QY1X&v=20190101
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4d51750c7ee1a35d36e68f34?client_id=WBVLIFMOB2B3KREKEPVECFKFZDJQJS2MCIXLERFTE4RZW0XA&client_secret=34TXWPRANTJP2E5QDBIKWEFTTPUKU3TOR2TR1I3GI0W4QY1X&v=20190101
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4d51750c7ee1a35d36e68f34?client_id=WBVLIFMOB2B3KREKEPVECFKFZDJQJS2MCIXLERFTE4RZW0XA&client_secret=34TXWPRANTJP2E5QDBIKWEFTTPUKU3TOR2TR1I3GI0W4QY1X&v=20190101
```

The id after https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/ must be always different, and I only get the first and the second id

I expect to see:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/557cda70498ec1b1d7c9bb38?...
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4d51750c7ee1a35d36e68f34?...
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4e4332422271bdbcf6659f9b?...
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4d63e05bdcafa1cd1e617611?...
etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do

```
for x,d in df.iterrows():
        url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{}?client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}'.format(d.venue_id, d.CLIENT_ID, d.CLIENT_SECRET, d.VERSION)
        print(url)
```